# чтение из универсального COM (USB to UART) порта

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial, uart

Имеется устройство (монетоприемник), который работает через Usb to UARТ на контролере CP2102.В диспетчере усройств этот дивайс строго устанавливается на com5. Когда приемный канал не чист, монетоприемник отправляет код ошибки, собственно который мне и нужно читать. Как можно реализовать чтение этого порта на пайтон?

Comment: Вы гуглили-гуглили и ничего не нагуглили? Тогда посмотрите направо на столбец "похожие"

Comment: я понимаю недовольство "более продвинутых", но когда не знаешь, как выглядит правильный ответ, то его сложно распознать. А как только поймешь, как именно выглядит правильный ответ - так сразу все стает очевидно.

Comment: Я искал в интернете, после этого напсиал здесь. Были похожие темы, однако я свой вопрос не нашел ответа.

Comment: В широком смысле ответ на вопрос `Как можно реализовать чтение этого порта на пайтон?` - использовать библиотеку, например - `pyserial`, и это легко найти, например, [таким запросом](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82). Но, может быть, вопрос в деталях?

Comment: читал несколько кодов с  с использованием pyserial. Однако не совсем понятно как  он работает. Возможно ли написать такой код, что бы читал указанный порт и отображал в командном строке?

Comment: через  python -m serial.tools.list_ports  отображает все доступные порты,  а вот как читать именно тот порт, который мне нужно? я новичок в сфере программирования, так что для меня очень многое пока как темный лес

Comment: с таким кодом  выдает параметры ком порта 5, но с кодом ошибки монетоприемника и без него быдает те же параметры...    import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate = 9600, timeout=2)
print(ser)

Comment: чтение порта (то есть, чтение с порта) это практически как чтения с сокета или файла. То есть, вначале нужно открыть и дальше читать. И вот в документации https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html прям есть примеры. посмотрите на них. Там прям второй пример уже то, что нужно

Comment: Serial<id=0x2726b8d9700, open=True>(port='COM5', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=2, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)   кроме таких параметров, что еще  можно получить как информацию?

Comment: А что Вы хотите получить? статус устройства (монетоприемника)? наверно с него нужно читать данные или вначале записать туда что то, а потом прочитать.  Но тут нужно читать документацию. Может у Вас есть уже готовая программа, которая это умеет делать?

Comment: Попробую объяснить... Извините за мой русский... Код ошибки можно увидеть через протокол ccTalk. Когда присутствует ошибка, в ccTalk выдает ошибка 254. И мне нужно как то получить информацию про наличии ошибки. В просторах интернета нашел сырой,нерабочий исходный код для протокола ccTalk. После чего решил получит интересующую мнея информацию через ком порт. Вот и задался вопросом, как можно через ком порт получить эту информацию?

Comment: я тут чуточку посмотрел, ccTalk - это полноценный протокол, так что просто так получит код ошибки - нельзя, нужно в порт отправить необходимую последовательность байт, а потом почитать ответ и проанализировать.  Но у меня нет ни нормального описания протокола, ни возможности как то это проверять.

Comment: В этом и вся проблема...  если через виртуальный  ком порт идет информация, можно как то "захватить" этот код. с ошибкой и без нее код будет отличться. думал если можно как то прочитать  порт,  разница в кодах даст результат.

Comment: Вы придумали себе "прочитать порт".  С ком портом это работает чуточку по другому. Тут как с файлом - можно читать байт за байтом. Но что бы это прочитать и понять, нужно знать протокол.

Comment: все сложнее, чем я думал)))

Comment: Спасибо... в документации ccTalk есть алгоритм для c++,  не знаю на сколько это поможет делу